# How to not crawl If the same as crawl data before in scrapy framework

Tags: python, http-headers, scrapy, last-modified

I wouldn't like to crawl If the same as crawl data before in scrapy framework.

In order to solve this problem, I think that when crawl was done, put date-time in the DB and do not crawl if Last-Modified response HTTP has not been updated since that date-time.

My questions are the following two.

1. How do you think about this way?Is there better Idea?
2. Could you teach me if there is a code that can reference the Last-Modified response HTTP control with scrapy framework?

Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: Use `Last-Modified` is a good idea. You can get response header via `response.headers`.

Answer (score 2):

Not all website return `Last-Modified` header, if you are certain your's does you can try having `HEAD` request first to check the headers and match with your DB info and then have `GET` request to crawl data:

```
def parse(self, response):
    urls = []  # some urls
    for url in urls:
        yield Request(url, method='HEAD', self.check)

def check(self, response):
    date = response.headers['Last-Modified']
    #check date to your db
    if db_date > date:  # or whatever is your case
        yield Request(response.url, self.success)

def success(self, response):
    yield item
```